# Git pull script using Github for windows

Tags: git, powershell, github, cmd, github-for-windows

I want to setup *.cmd or *.ps1 script which executes `git pull` at specific directory.
I am using Github for Windows and repository is hosted on Github.

So I need a script that does two steps.

1. Goes to a directory (my local repository)
2. Perform a git pull.

How can I achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

How are you going to pull if there's no git folder in that directory? you could replace `git pull` with `git clone url`

```
pushd somepath
git pull
```

Comment: There must be .git in that directory...  
What I want is to pull from remote via script

Comment: well, it magically must be there or how is it going to be there?

Comment: well then, you don't need to do git clone, just do ``pushd`` and ``git pull``

Answer (score 0):

I've found solution:

locate `C:\Users\UMCS-Supervisor\AppData\Local\GitHub\PortableGit_<GUID>` then make XYZ.cmd
Then in XYZ.cmd edit as the following

```
cd "C:\Directory\To\your\Git\folder"
git pull https://Username:Password@github.com/Username/RepoName.git
```

Answer (score -2):

This is not quite a powershell script, but this may work!

Try creating a .sh file with the following script:

```
#!/bin/sh
cd "C:\Directory\To\your\Git\folder"
git pull
echo Press Enter...
read
```

Also, for committing and pushing,

```
#!/bin/sh
cd "C:\Directory\To\your\Git\folder"
git add .
echo -n "Commit Message: "
read message
git commit -m "$message"
git push
echo Press Enter...
read
```

Alternatively, you can place a .sh script in your repository folder that runs without changing directory.

I just have a push_git.sh and pull_git.sh file in my repo, so when I am working on it I can just double click them and pull or push.

Hope this helps!

Comment: This is not even a powershell script